# mod_rewrite adding documentroot to url

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, virtualhost

The following rewrite redirects `http://example.com/` to `http://example.com/www/www.example.com/public_html` instead of `http://www.example.com/`. `/www/www.example.com/public_html` is the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot).

```
# Rewrite Rules for Example
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect from example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirect is in a [`<VirtualHost *:80>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) with the settings:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

Options +FollowSymLinks
DocumentRoot /www/www.example.com/public_html

and the rewrite is inside <Directory />
```

Any ideas why it would do this? I looked into the [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and it says that using [`${HTTP_HOST}`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) in your [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) will add the host to the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) instead of just the [URL-Path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax). Well this is a VERY common rewrite, and I've never seen this happen before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was `<Directory />`. Once I updated it to `<Directory /www/www.example.com/public_html>` it worked just fine.